# Topologically distinguishing Mobius Strips based on the number of half-twists

Tags: general-topology, mobius-band

We can distinguish between a (closed) Mobius strip and 'regular' (untwisted) strip by examining the set of points which have no neighborhood homeomorphic to a disk (intuitively, the 'boundary' of the strip).  For a Mobius strip, this set is connected, while for an untwisted strip the set has two connected components.

However, the above criteria cannot distinguish between, say, a Mobius strip with 1 half-twist and a Mobius strip with 3 half-twists; it can only tell us if the number of twists is even or odd.

Can we tell how many half-twists a strip has in a purely topological way that avoids the embedding of the strip in $\mathbb{R}^3$?  The more I think about it, the less convinced I am that we can.  I can show all strips with an even number of half-twists are homeomorphic to $[0,1] \times S^1$ (by coordinatizing one of the circles as $\{0\} \times S^1$, the other as $\{1\}\times S^1$, and interpolating in between), but I'm not sure how or if I can adapt this approach to the case when there is an odd number of half-twists.

Comment: Yes, Mobius strips with an odd number of twists are homeomorphic to the standard strip.

Comment: @MikeMiller Is this true if the strips are closed?  If so, why does my argument in the first paragraph not work?

Comment: @MikeMiller Or do you mean the standard Mobius strip?  If so, I'd be interested to see an explicit homeomorphism.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right in not being convinced: the parity of the number of twists is a topological invariant, but the actual number is not. To see this think of the strip as $I \times I$ (where $I = [0, 1]$) with opposite edges $\{0\} \times I$ and $\{1\} \times I$ identified either by $(0, x) \mapsto (1, x)$ (for an even number of twists) or by $(0, x) \mapsto (1, 1-x)$ (for an odd number of twists).

Comment: I like this argument, thanks!