# Can a torus be cut into a Möbius strip with zero number of half twists?

Tags: algebraic-topology

It is known that the torus can be cut into a Möbius strip with an even number $n$ of half twists(half twist means rotation 180 degree). I am asking if it is possible to $n$ to be zero?

Comment: A strip with an even number of half twists is not a Möbius strip, it is an annulus.

Comment: Just cutting along the torus without disconnecting the set

Comment: Is a strip with even number of half twists equivalent to annulus, because annulus is with no half twists

Answer (score 3):

If you think of a torus by taking a cylinder and identifying its ends, then it is clear that cutting along this circle gives you a cylinder (a Möbius strip with zero half twists).

Comment: Thank you, I got the idea. I just have a small question whether a strip with even number of half twists is equivalent to annulus (strip with no half twists)

Comment: @user134875 Topologically, yes. If you think a Möbius strip as a unit square with the ends identified, then you can see that they are the same.

Comment: @user134875 see the answer here for a more detailed explanation http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379300/topologically-distinguishing-mobius-strips-based-on-the-number-of-half-twists

Comment: I understand, I am very grateful. Thank you.