# Twisting the unit square n times before gluing( 2.1.6 in G&P).

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, mobius-band

The question is given below:

[image]

I have made a Mobius band with a paper and twisted it 3-times but I could not describe what I see it may be a 3 knot shape, could anyone give me a hint for solving that question please?

**EDIT:**

The answer to my previous question is here:

[Topologically distinguishing Mobius Strips based on the number of half-twists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379300/topologically-distinguishing-mobius-strips-based-on-the-number-of-half-twists)

But still I do not know how to prove that the boundary of the cylinder is 2 copies of $S^1$ and that of the Mobius band is 1 copy of $S^1$, could anyone help me in doing so?

Comment: If you twist 3 times before gluing, the boundary will again be a single circle.

Comment: Try cutting the band down the middle and seeing what you get in each case. . Also try cutting it 1/3rd from the edge. These are amusing  things to show children.

Comment: @RonnieBrown Could you please Dr Ronnie provide me with a site to increase my imagination in this field of study ?

Comment: I hope www.groupoids.org.uk    will help. There is of course lots of stuff out there other than mine!

Comment: you could have some fun with mathematical models, and also origami!

Comment: What is origami ? @RonnieBrown  I am from a poor country where imagination and respecting minds is not cultivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, you cannot tell a manifold with one even number of twists from one with some other even number.  They are all orientable.  The ones with an odd number of twists are non-orientable, but you can't tell one odd number from another.  The boundary is $2$ copies of $S^1$ for the even case and $1$ copy of $S^1$ for the odd.

Comment: How can I prove rigorously that the boundary of the cylinder is 2 copies of $S^1$?

Comment: You parameterize the side of the square from $0$ to $1$ and note that the gluing identified $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Could you provide more details please about this in your answer ? Also How can I prove rigorously that the boundary of the mobius band is one copy of $S^1$?

Comment: And I think that the answer will be divided according to if n is even or odd, so I think if I twist odd number of times the result wil lbe isomorphic to the mobius band and if I twisted even number of times the result will be isomorphic to the cylinder ..... am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: but what isomorphism should I use?

Comment: You can just use the isomorphism that maps each point on the untwisted square to the corresponding point on the twisted square.  The neighborhood of each point is the same as long as the parity of the number of twists is the same.  The only difference is the embedding in $\Bbb R^3$, which is not a property of the surface.  If the parity is different this isomorphism does not work for points on the edge.

Comment: The answer to some of my questions to you is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379300/topologically-distinguishing-mobius-strips-based-on-the-number-of-half-twists

Comment: @hopefully You can find out on origami from a web search. All you need is paper and scissors. I hope you can find these.